# Post type as radio elements for a featured function

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I display a post type as radio elements in the frontend of my website, so that a user can select one of the posts to be displayed on another page? I want to implement a "featured" function, where the selected post will be displayed on another page.

```
<?php
$attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 500,
    'post_status'    => 'any',
'post_parent'    => null,
    'author'        =>  $current_user->ID
) );

if ( $attachments ) {

    echo "<form>";
    foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        echo "<div>";
        echo "<input type='radio' name='fav_language' value=''>";
        echo "<img src='";
        echo esc_html( get_the_content() );
        echo "'></div>";
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo "</form>";
}
?>`
```